# Android - Read preference from service which is running in separate process

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

I am writing some value to default shared preference using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)` from the Activity(Default process).

I have one more `Foreground Service` which is running in **Separate process** using `android:process=":processName"`.

Now the issue is when I try to read the preference value from `Foreground Service` it is not able to read the value which was written from the `Activity`.

But when I remove the `android:process=":processName"` attribute from the `Foreground Service` registration element in Android Manifest it starts working, service is able to read the value from preference which was written from the `Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

> Note: This class does not support use across multiple processes.

Create some sort of API between the two processes and communicate that way.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences does not support multiple processes so either you can make service and app in same process or you can use content providers for multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

Store the information in SQLite database. This works well with multiple processes and is realtively lightweight.